# Silex Setting Middleware to a ControllerCollection

Tags: middleware, silex

I want to do something like this:

```
$app->mount('dashboard', new Travel\Controllers\Dashboard())->before(function() use ($app) {
              //check if is logued...
            })
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do

```
$controllers = $app["controllers_factory"];
$controllers->before(function(Request $request){});
```

in you `ControllerProviderInterface::connect` method

if you need a function defined in `$app` definition php file you can create a protected function

```
$app['callback'] = $app->protect(function(){});
```

then

```
$controllers->before($app["callback"]);
```